# Navigate to specific tab from Drawer Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to nest a Tab Navigator inside of a Drawer Navigator and then navigate to a specific tab from the Drawer?

Consider this very basic set up:

```
const PrimaryNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ScreenOne,
  ScreenTwo
 })

export const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: PrimaryNav,
    drawerLabel: 'Option 1',
  },
  Investment: {
    screen: PrimaryNav,
    drawerLabel: 'Option 2',
  }
})
```

Obviously, this set up will just resolve to the first item in the TabNav regardless of which option you click.

Is there a way to pass an option to navigate to each of those tabs specifically? I know it would be possible to just pass ScreenOne and ScreenTwo to the "screen" options in DrawerNavigator, but I would like to retain the tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a hacky workaround [mentioned](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1715#issuecomment-359286503) in react-navigation GitHub issues page:

```
navigation.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'PrimaryNav' })]
    })
);
navigation.navigate('ScreenTwo'))
```

Not the best solution, but the only thing I could find when I faced the same problem.

Comment: Does this solution work for navigating from a react-navigation navigator item? Where can I attach an onClick handler in a Drawer Item?

Comment: @connor I believe it should. What kind of drawer items are you using? I think you can handle clicks by using the prop `onPress` for most of the RN components. Something like this: `<View onPress={ () => this.goToScreenTwo() }> <Text>Sign Out</Text> </View>` and put the code above in a separate `goToScreenTwo()` method in your component class.

Comment: Thank you for helping me get to the solution. I did not see there was a `contentComponent` property I could pass to `createDrawerNavigator` to create my own custom component.

Comment: Glad to know that! :)

Comment: Is there any other way to do this, I'd prefer to not have to track navigation via redux if possible?

Answer (score 8):

2020: navigating through nested navigators

```
onPress={() => {
  navigation.navigate('Root', {
  screen: 'Screen'
});
```